# Grab form fields and calculate based on inputs

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an `undefined` error and don't know why this isn't working.

It's supposed to divide the rent by the amount of roommates:

```js
function splitRent() {

  var roommates = document.getElementById("rent");
  var rent = document.getElementById("rent");
  var rentEach = rent / roommates;

  if (document.getElementById("submit") == true) {

    document.write("You each should pay" + " " + rentEach)

  } else {

    document.alert("Gimme info")
  }

};
```

```html
<h1>Roommate Room Splitter</h1>

<form id="myForm">
  Roommates:
  <input type="text" name="roommates" id="roommates">
  <br/>Rent:
  <input type="text" name="rent" id="rent">
  <br/>

  <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="splitRent()" />

</form>
```

Comment: For starters your code is getting the value of `rent` for both variables `roommates` and `rent` :)  Otherwise you need to add a `.value` to the end of your `getElementById()`, you are just returning the element, not its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take the `value` of the fields, not the fields themselves.

`document.getElementById()` returns the node, but you want the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/value) of the `input` field:

```
var rent = document.getElementById("rent").value;
```

Also, you're getting the value of the rent twice; you want to check the roommates as well.

```
var roommates = document.getElementById("roommates").value;
```

Lastly, `document.getElementById("submit") == true` doesn't mean anything: you're comparing a button node with a boolean value, which doesn't make sense. If you want to check to make sure that both fields are filled, try this:

```
if(roommates && rent){
    //do calculations
}else{
   window.alert("Enter something"); //note that it's window.alert(), not document.alert(), which is not a function
```

As it stands, this allows people to enter things that are not numbers; there are two things that you could do to fix that.

1. Use `parseInt()`/`parseFloat()` to ensure that you're extracting a number
2. Check that you actually have a number before doing calculations

You'd do something like this:

```
var rent = parseInt(document.getElementById("rent").value);
var roommates = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rooommates").value);
```

If you use the checking I've done above (`rent && roommates`), the validation will take place there (it checks for both empty and `NaN` values).

```js
function splitRent() {

  var roommates = parseInt(document.getElementById("roommates").value);
  var rent = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rent").value);
  var rentEach = rent / roommates;

  if (roommates && rent) {

    document.write("You each should pay" + " " + rentEach)

  } else {

    window.alert("Gimme info")
  }

};
```

```html
<h1>Roommate Room Splitter</h1>

<form id="myForm">
  Roommates:
  <input type="text" name="roommates" id="roommates">
  <br/>Rent:
  <input type="text" name="rent" id="rent">
  <br/>

  <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="splitRent()" />

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I feel so dumb about that rent/roommate situation, but you really cleared it up for me! I'm obviously new. One question though... I can get a response to splitRent if I write window.alert ("You each should pay" + " " + rentEach). However, I can't get it to write to the page using document.write, is there a reason for this?

Comment: @dshesh I'm glad I could help! If my answer solved your issue, please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that we both gain [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't this be:

```
    var roommates = document.getElementById("roommates").value;
    var rent = document.getElementById("rent").value;
```

Do you always get "1" for your result?

Comment: Adding a `.value` on the end of each of the `getElementById()` might help too ;)  (No I didn't down vote)